# Z-Index not showing element on top

Tags: html, css

On the following page: http://jsfiddle.net/3h7pL/

I'm having an issue where the submenu isn't showing up no matter what I do with the z-index or positioning.  When you mouse over "Round Robins" you should see a bulleted list appear below it.  You'll see it in the markup, but the CSS won't show it.  I've had a rough time determining why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
nav > ul:hover {z-index: 3}
```

Your `nav` at `z-index: 1` is hiding under the `contentBody` of `z-index: 2`.

**Update:** However, that solution ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3h7pL/1/)) messes up your shadowing. If you remove all the `z-index` from all the `nav` elements except this:

```
nav > ul > li:hover ul {
         z-index: 3;
         display: block;
     }
```

[Then it works without messing up shadowing](http://jsfiddle.net/3h7pL/3/).